# Azure SignalR Connection Count never decreasing

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr

I'm trying to figure out why the "Connection Count" of my Azure SignalR resource basically never decreases. The only time it does, it drops drastically, just like it was recycled or something similar.

We automatically connect the user to SignalR when they login to our website, and I would presume that SignalR picks up the deconnect when the user leaves the website. But it doesn't look like it does.

I would have suspected that we have up to 1000 users visiting the site at the same time, but that can't be the case since they would've reconnected after the drop (we have a reconnect functionality implemented)

What I'm looking for is help on how to debug this? How can I figure out why the connection count doesn't decrease?

Npm: `"@aspnet/signalr": "1.0.3"`

Nuget: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.SignalR" Version="1.0.8" />`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's not only the frontend that uses SignalR clients, but also some of our background processes (that pushes messages out to the frontend). I forgot about these, and it seems like they aren't being disposed correctly, so the connection remains open.